# Сортировка и вывод по условию в датасете pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Имеется следующий датасет (строк много):

|  | date | user | event_type | parameter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-04-01_00:01:08 770906 | 770906 | 3 | unknown |
| 1 | 2020-04-01_00:00:30 527877 | 527877 | 1 | text |
| 2 | 2020-04-01_00:01:12 539948 | 539948 | 3 | picture |
| 3 | 2020-04-01_00:01:20 107541 | 107541 | 3 | picture |
| 4 | 2020-04-01_00:01:38 374954 | 374954 | 4 | text |

Пробовал вот так:

```py
df.date = df.date.str.replace(r'\s.*','', regex=True)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
df[df['date']=='2020-04-18' + pd.Timedelta(30, "m")]
```

Но выдает ошибку:

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Timedelta") to str`

Подскажите, как решить?

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @SwaD `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Timedelta") to str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С подсветкой синтаксиса, конечно, понятнее что у Вас происходит.
Фильтровать `datetime` по строчной переменной нельзя

Можно так:

```python
df[df['date'].dt.date==pd.to_datetime('2020-04-18')]
```

`.dt.date` обрезает `datetime` с временем до даты и сравнивает с датой `pd.to_datetime('2020-04-18')`
Таким образом получаем все записи на данную дату игнорируя время.

Альтернативно можно обращаться к году, месяцу и дню непосредственно:

```python
df[(df['date'].dt.year == 2020) & (df['date'].dt.month == 4) & (df['date'].dt.day == 18)]
```

Если в dataset только один день, то можно сократить до:

```python
df[df['date'].dt.day == 18]
```

---

Что касается `timedelta`, её добавлять можно исключительно к колонке:

```python
df[df['date'].dt.day == 18]['date'] + pd.Timedelta(30, "m")
```

Кстати, обращаться к колонке можно через `.`:

```python
df[df.date.dt.day == 18].date + pd.Timedelta(30, "m")
```

---

В качестве прямо совсем альтернативы, можно не приводить колонку `date` к `datetime` и фильтровать по строковой переменной:

```python
d̶f̶.̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶d̶f̶.̶d̶a̶t̶e̶.̶s̶t̶r̶.̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶(̶r̶'̶\̶s̶.̶*̶'̶,̶'̶'̶,̶ ̶r̶e̶g̶e̶x̶=̶T̶r̶u̶e̶)̶
̶d̶f̶.̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶p̶d̶.̶t̶o̶_̶d̶a̶t̶e̶t̶i̶m̶e̶(̶d̶f̶.̶d̶a̶t̶e̶,̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶=̶'̶%̶Y̶-̶%̶m̶-̶%̶d̶_̶%̶H̶:̶%̶M̶:̶%̶S̶'̶)̶
df[df.date.str.contains('2020-04-18')]
```

Но `timedelta` с этим делом работать не будет.

Comment: На самом деле со строками даты можно сравнивать. Но таймдельту при этом добавлять нельзя, да.

Comment: @CrazyElf это если колонка Date как `object` идёт. Или я чего то упускаю? Можно пример?

Comment: Нет, именно когда колонка типа `datetime`, то есть такой код вполне работает: `df[df['date']=='2020-04-18']` ну, если дата в колонке точная, без времени в данном случае. `Pandas` такое умеет. И больше-меньше тоже так умеет.

Comment: @CrazyElf вижу [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates) такую нотацию, да. Да и припоминаю, что вроде должно. Но по факту такой фильтр пустую таблицу выдаёт, даже если к дате привести `df.date = df.date.dt.date`. Возможно что-то поменяли в новых версиях.